# How can I install Storybook for react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, storybook

I have a fresh Expo project and I would like to add Storybook for all the components, the documentation seems deprecated, does anyone know how to install the latest version?

Comment: Which documentation is deprecated? [This](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/)?

Comment: Yes, as it says: it has not been updated to the latest version of Storybook yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried the [docs](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/) and I got Storybook on [my Expo project](https://github.com/simo54/taskbox) (**no longer available**).

Answering your question, the package is not deprecated because, I quote,

> This community translation has not been updated to the latest version of Storybook yet.

For future reference, during the installation process I faced the following "freeze" using Git Bash, if you get the same just `ctrl + c` to resume your terminal.

[image]